# Is there a faster alternative to this code for remove stopwords and punctuation in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, nltk

the code i use seems too slow, perhaps there is an alternative.

in Pandas I tokenized the dataframe column 'description' and made a list of stopwords + punctuations to be removed, and then attempted to remove the useless words.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import nltk
import string
nltk.download("stopwords")
nltk.download('punkt')

df2 = pd.read_csv('xxx')
```

after cleaning, etc. endedup with around 135.000 rows and no nulls

```
description points  price
0   This tremendous 100% varietal wine hails from ...   96  235.0
1   Ripe aromas of fig, blackberry and cassis are ...   96  110.0
2   Mac Watson honors the memory of a wine once ma...   96  90.0
3   This spent 20 months in 30% new French oak, an...   96  65.0
4   This is the top wine from La Bégude, named aft...   95  66.0
```

then tokenize

```
df2['description'] = df2.apply(lambda row: 
nltk.word_tokenize(row['description']), axis=1)
df2.head()
```

tokenize was pretty fast. now defining the useless words:

```
useless_words = nltk.corpus.stopwords.words("english") + 
list(string.punctuation)
```

and now trying to use the same trick to remove the useless words from `df2['description']`

```
df2['description'] = df2.apply(lambda row: [word for word in 
df2['description'] if not word in useless_words], axis=1)
```

i expected this to be more fast, but it's taking time to compute. i'm new to coding so thought maybe you guys know an alternative to handle this and reuce computing time. also maybe i didn't do it right i don't know, so i ask and thank in advance.

Comment: for starters, pandas isn't the best tool for this, just use vanilla python,  but in either case, conver `useless_words` into a `set`

Comment: Try using spacy.io instead of nltk. nltk is for learning, spacy is for production.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this ?

```
df2["description"] = df2["description"].str.lower()
df2["description"] = df2["description"].str.replace("|".join(useless_words), "")
```

Comment: it returned NaNs (and now I'm confused)

Comment: @JavierEspinozaTraslaviña is the `useless_words` a list?

Comment: @JavierEspinozaTraslaviña see my edited answer then tell me the result. I'll try to help you.

Comment: yeah thank's, but I found another way. now I have a second problem haha thank you :)

Comment: no problem, here: `df2['bag_of_words'] = df2['description'].apply(lambda x: [item for item in x if item not in useless_words])`

i sliced 10 rows for testing and discovered that the code i tryed first returned the same list for in each row of the column. so this way i knew it was wrong.